What measure can Bangladesh take according to international law?
A few days ago, the Bangladesh consulate in the Tripura province of India was attacked by mobs:

Bangladesh's interim government said that protesters had broken down the mission's main gate, damaged property inside, vandalised the flag pole and desecrated the national flag, leaving staff with a "deep sense of insecurity".

What measure can Bangladesh take according to international law?

The linked article does state that the Indian government expressed regrets and will take steps to prevent that happening in the future.  Maybe this could be considered "good enough" at this time, at least if it doesn't happen again?  I suspect most countries would think so, India certainly will and Bangladesh probably should be careful in antagonizing its bigger neighbor overmuch.  Indian nationalism sometimes makes for unpleasant behavior, but Bangladesh does seem like it's got other fish to fry.

What measure can Bangladesh take - What do you think Bangladesh wants from India in this instance? The answer depends on the outcome Bangladesh seeks ...

What person things this belongs on politics Meta!?!?

Depends on how far they want to go.

Have their ambassador to India (who is called High Commissioner between many Commonwealth countries) deliver a protest note.
Summon the Indian ambassador to Bangladesh to listen to a protest.
Recall their ambassador for 'consultations,' thereby temporarily downgrading the level of diplomatic relations.
Sever diplomatic relations.
Conclude that they believe that the Indian government was complicit, declare war on India, and invade.


Are there also other legal possibilities like sueing in front of some international court for failing to provide sufficient security maybe? I didn't think there is or that such a case would be successful, just checking.
